# PyQt5 Application Not Inheriting qt5ct Style

Tags: python, qt, anaconda, pyqt5

My PyQt5 application only uses windows or fusion style. It's not inheriting GTK style set in qt5ct.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QStyleFactory
print(QStyleFactory.keys())
**['Windows', 'Fusion']**
```

Things attempted:

1. Install qt5ct & qt-styleplugins
2. Set qt5ct to gtk2

My "~/.profile" looks like this:

```
export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME="gtk2"
export QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0 
export QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE="gtk2"
export EDITOR=/usr/bin/nano
export GTK2_RC_FILES="$HOME/.gtkrc-2.0"
```

I have tried including/excluding override with & without quotes, using gtk+, gtk instead of gtk2 as well without success.

Other Non-anaconda based QT based applications such as vlc inherit from the gtk style set. I'm guessing this is because there are two versions of QT (one installed by anaconda and the other by pacman in Arch Linux).

Would anyone have a solution for this? Using fusion/windows in a linux environment is looking quite ugly.

Thanks.

Comment: what is the output of `print(QtCore.QCoreApplication.libraryPaths())`?

Comment: try with: `os.environ["QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME"] = "gtk2"` `QtCore.QCoreApplication.addLibraryPath("/usr/lib/qt/plugins")`

Comment: output for library path initially is is : ['/opt/anaconda/plugins']. After adding qt plugin path, it becomes ['/usr/lib/qt/plugins', '/opt/anaconda/plugins']. Changing platform theme to gtk2 still looks the same.  Thanks.

Comment: It seems to me that the problem in this case is the Qt versions so you must compile qt-styleplugins for the specific version that anaconda uses.

Comment: Ah! Would you know how to make qt5-styleplugins compile with anaconda's qt version?

Comment: First get the Qt version: `from PyQt5 import Qt` `print(Qt.QT_VERSION_STR)`, install that version of Qt and use the qmake of that version to compile that module

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate your inputs. To avoid complications, I ended up creating a custom css based out of Ubuntu from here: https://github.com/GTRONICK/QSS . I've themed it to look better, so this should do for me.

Comment: Very odd. I did "pip install PyQt5" and now it overrides & uses the GTK theme...